# Using an external javascript file in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What I'm trying to do is to include google translate api in my firefox addon.
I'm writing it with the addon builder.
I already tried to load dynamically the script in the head section of the document but it doesn't work and I get no error, nothing.
here's the code:

```
var fileref = doc.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=st.gApiInit");

if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {
  object=doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  object.appendChild(fileref);
}
```

If I look a the source code of the page I cannot find the added element

Comment: What is `object`? Is that supposed to be `window`? And what is `doc`? (I've never developed FF add-ons)

Answer (score 0):

Where are your code executed? It look like is a content script, Addon Builder is base on Addon-SDK. You should put these code the a file. Here is the [document](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/modifying-web-pages-tab.html).

I think the best way to do this is use Greasemonkey.